# Gap caused by border in safari in IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

Something weird.

A div inside a parent div. Parent div has a border. Then in safari in ios devices. There's a small gap between the border and the child div. Wonder if anyone knows why is this and how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Here is the code and a screenshot:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .laoda {
            border-top: solid 1em #c53243;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .laoer {
            background: #c53243;
            height: 5.7em;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<div class="laoda">
    <div class="laoer"></div>
</div>
```

Can't post image yet. Here is a screenshot to the image: http://s1.tt.tl/image.png

And here is the web page with the code: http://s1.tt.tl/t.html

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `line-height:0` to both classes.